# How to get documents from current calendar day in Mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I was trying to google this but found nothing and was surprised so I will ask the question for the sake of the search engines.

Is there a way to get all the existing documents for the current calendar day given a specific time zone? I imagine I will be roping together moment-timezone and Mongoose but am wondering if code already exists for this so I don't have to start from scratch, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a collection `col` with the field `dateTime` of type [BSON date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/index.html#date) interpreted as **UTC**. Then you want to get all the documents for 25th of December for `America/New_York` timezone (where calendar day starts 5 hours after UTC). To do that you can use [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) operator in Aggregation Framework and pass the timezone as a parameter:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $and: [
                    { $gte: [ "$dateTime", { $dateFromParts: { 'year' : 2018, 'month' : 12, 'day': 25, timezone: 'America/New_York'  } } ] },
                    { $lte: [ "$dateTime", { $dateFromParts: { 'year' : 2018, 'month' : 12, 'day': 26, timezone: 'America/New_York'  } } ] }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

`timezone` expression can either be an [Olson timezone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (like `America/New_York`) or a UTC offset like `+05:00`

Comment: This particular command doesn't seem to work for me but I think I'll be able to use $dateFromParts with the Olson timezone identifier to get it to work, thanks and I'll report back shortly.

Comment: Was my fault, I didn't change $dateTime to $createdAt, did some testing and this works thanks a lot for a solid answer!